# How to update child document in Elastic search using update API?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use parent-child documents in Elastic Search.  I can do partial updates of the master document using the _update api.  However, if I use the _update APi on a child document, the content of the document is completely replaced by the content of my script.  Something goes wrong ... and I do not know what ....

See example below:

**CREATE CHILD DOCUMENT**

```
POST to /indexName/comment/c006?parent=b003
{
  "authorId": "ps101",
  "authorFullName": "Lieven",
  "body": "Comment text comes here",
  "isApproved": false
}
```

**GET CHILD**

```
GET to /indexName/comment/c006?parent=b003
{
_index: "indexName"
_type: "comment"
_id: "c006"
_version: 20
found: true
-_source: {
   authorId: "ps101"
   authorFullName: "Lieven"
   body: "Comment text comes here."
   isApproved: false
  }
}
```

**PARTIAL UPDATE**

```
POST TO /indexName/comment/c006?parent=b003/_update
{
   "script" : "ctx._source.isAcceptedAnswer=value",
   "params" : {
      "value" : true
   }
}
```

**NOW, GET AGAIN THE CHILD**

```
GET to /indexName/comment/c006?parent=b003
{
_index: "indexName"
_type: "comment"
_id: "c006"
_version: 21
found: true
-_source: {
   script: "ctx._source.isAcceptedAnswer=value"
   -params: {
   value: true
   }
  }
}
```

Source is completely wrong ...

Hope somebody can help
Marc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
POST TO /indexName/comment/c006?parent=b003/_update
```

to

```
POST TO /indexName/comment/c006/_update?parent=b003
```

The ? is the beginning of the query string,  and it goes on the end.